# Как избавится от закрепленных картинок в электронных письмах при верстке?

Tags: html, email, рассылка

[image: картинки которые в списке электронных почт]

Сверстал письмо для электронной почты и эти картинки бесят.
каждая картинка весит меньше 100кб все alt написал

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Просто не прикрепляйте изображения к письму